Multi-variate incomplete beta functions
I am trying to generalize the following integral
$$I_0=\int_{[0,1]^n}\text{d}\vec{x} \delta\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j-1\right)\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{-p}=B_n(1-p,\dots,1-p)$$
where $B_n$ is the multi-variate Beta function of $n$ arguments, and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta enforcing the sum of the $x_i$ to be 1, to the case where the integral boundaries are of the form $x_i\in[0,m_i]$ and $m_i\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$I_M=\int_{\Omega_M}\text{d}\vec{x} \delta\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j-1\right)\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{-p}$$
with $\Omega_M=[0,m_1]\times[0,m_2]\times\dots\times[0,m_n]$. I know that the incomplete beta function is given by
$$B(x;a,b)=\int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$
and I'm hoping to express the integral $I_M$ as a multi-variate incomplete beta function or as a product of incomplete beta functions. Does such a closed form exist?

What is $\delta$ here? There may be a closed form via the Lauricella functions
